# Can a group of 4 people share a map and combine updates in SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If we

1. Create a zoom level 4 map
2. Clone it 3 times

and then distribute the 4 maps. Will we all see updates as the 4 of us explore in different directions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, cloned maps are exact duplicates at all times, and players can update the shared map simultaneously, plus see each other on the map.

There was once a bug, though, that corrupted all instances of a cloned map in multiplayer, if even one of them was ever placed into item frame. Maps would still function, but the player marker would be drawn underneath the map itself, so could only be seen when a player was on the edge or outside the map. This may have been fixed, or not.